# Something wrong with URLs after sandbox refresh

Tags: apexrest, sandbox-refresh

Before refresh, an Apex REST service worked with the URL below.

https:// DOMAIN_NAME/CUSTOM_PATH_A/services/apexrest/REST_SERVICE_NAME

This URL is to expose data in XML format for other system.

After refresh, when accessed, the response became a "under construction" page instead of XML, and says
"https:// DOMAIN_NAME/CUSTOM_PATH_B is under construction."

I don't understand

- why the XML is not correctly show even though the same source code and settings is well working on production environment
- why the page says "https:// DOMAIN_NAME/CUSTOM_PATH_B is under construction." even though I tried to access path under https:// DOMAIN_NAME/CUSTOM_PATH_A

Does anyone has any idea?

==============

Update 05-Nov-2015

Noticed that this issue is now resolved somehow... don't know why ... thanks!

Comment: sometimes with Sandbox refresh your base url and instance got changes exa: CS1 to CS2. Please check your URL.

Comment: Thanks Tushar for a quick response. Yes, the base url changed from xxx-yyy.cs6.force.com to xxx-yyy.cs5.force.com, so I'm using the new one but it doesn't help.

Comment: then try to open this page in browser and check it display correctly. may be some permission issue.

Comment: Tried to open the page in web browser so many times, but it always says "https:// DOMAIN_NAME/CUSTOM_PATH_B is under construction." :-<

Comment: Then its a permission issue. May be that page not publicly available.  Please check all page assignment and your debug log too.

Comment: 1 - Check if site is active. 2- Check Active Site Home Page and confirm that it has your desired page name as value.

Comment: 1 - yes, the site is surely active. 2 - Active Site Home Page value is set as a VisualForce page name which is unrelated to the REST service. The situation is the same as the one in production env, whose REST service is correctly working.

Comment: Checked the site permission to find no problem...  the Apex Class name is in the list of "Enabled Apex Class Access" of the site concerned. I'm going to check debug log.

Comment: How about domain mapping, is it fine ?

Comment: @AmitBangad , what do you mean by "domain mapping"? I think there's certainly some issue at domain or path because the salesforce says "https:// DOMAIN_NAME/CUSTOM_PATH_B is under construction" even though I accessed https:// DOMAIN_NAME/CUSTOM_PATH_A/services/apexrest/REST_SERVICE_NAME , but I'm at a loss how to solve this...  strangely, the situation is the same after I deactivated the site https:// DOMAIN_NAME/CUSTOM_PATH_B .

Comment: Not 100% sure but checkout these links if they are helpful - https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000205653&language=en_US https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=siteforce_domains.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Thanks @AmitBangad, but our DOMAIN_NAME is in a form of mysandbox-mycompany.cs5.force.com, so I think we don't need to register CNAME record... am I right?